# How to make a method that rotates a UIView work many times

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I have a view that slides up from the bottom of the screen when the user swipes up and when this happen a little arrow is supposed to rotate so that it is now pointing downwards. In a similar fashion, when the view is slid away to the bottom of the screen, the arrow should rotate again so that it points upwards. Ideally, I would like to call the same method every time the view slides in or out to rotate the arrow 180 degrees. Right now I am using:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    viewToBeRotated.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
}];
```

This works fine the first time but then doesn't do anything on further method calls, any pointers on how to do do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set a transform on a view you erase previous transform.
To have multiple transforms applied to one view at the same time you must "add" them. Each CGAffineTransformMake{Rotation/Scale/etc} has an equivalent which allows you to "add" a transform to another one.

To resolve your issue you can use the following :

```
self.iv.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.iv.transform, M_PI);
```